# How to pass select option to popup dialog -php codeginiter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using php codeginiter.

I have the form with select option control. It will process the delete user function. I want to show the popup dialog with showing some user information and confirm delete button. How to pass information from form to popup dialog? As I try to do below but seems something wrong:

```
<select id="sellerID"..> </select> // it will assign hidden variable userID after onchange on select.
<input type="hidden" id="userID" >
<a href="#popupdialoig" var1=<?php echo $username;?> ...> click </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

better to use ajax call on select function and get the according name in ajax call and set it to popup dialog. like

```
  <select id="sellerID" onchange="onChangeSelect(this.value)"> </select>

  function onChangeSelect(selectedid)
  {
    $.post(getNames.php,{id:selectedid},function(data)
    {
       var name = data;
       $('#popupdialoig').attr('var1',name);
    });
  }
```